# How do I change slate editor value using Javascript (DOM manipulation)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, slate.js

I want to change the text in the slate editor using DOM manipulation via Javascript.

Dynamically change the values filled into editable components in a particular webpage.
The website has a combination of simple input elements and slate editor. The values input into these fields are saved once the focus gets off them.

I have managed to change the text of normal input elements and on blur the data a gets saved.
I am not sure how to achieve the same behaviour on slate editor elements.

I have tried to dispatch events on the slate editor component using `dispatchEvent`, but it did not work.

```
<div
  data-slate-editor="true"
  data-key="18"
  contenteditable="true"
  class="
    uta_c_editor__slate-editor uta_c_editor__slate-editor--dictation-disabled
  "
  autocorrect="on"
  spellcheck="false"
  role="textbox"
  data-gramm="false"
  style="
    outline: none;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    -webkit-user-modify: read-write-plaintext-only;
  "
>
  <div data-slate-object="block" data-key="19" style="position: relative">
    <span data-slate-object="text" data-key="20"
      ><span data-slate-leaf="true" data-offset-key="20:0"
        ><span data-slate-string="true">Testing in progress.</span></span
      ></span
    >
  </div>
</div>
```

Tried dispatching the below event on this element.

```
let changeEvent = new Event('change', { 
'bubbles': true, 
'detail': {
    value: "Testing Slate Js"
 } });

targetSlateElement.dispatchEvent(changeEvent)
```

Tried to update its textContent like below:

```
targetSlateElement.textContent = "Testing Slate JS"
```

Above method did change its content value but on blur it it resets the content to older content.

Comment: Please add the sample code or a link to codepen/codesandbox that you have tried.

Comment: @VijayDev   I dispatched the below event on the target element for slate js editor. let changeEvent  = new Event('change', { 'bubbles': true, 'detail': {value: "Testing Slate Js"} });

Comment: @saichaitanya a minimal reproducible on https://codesandbox.io/s/0qor7onxy0 would be nice.

Comment: @saichaitanya Just curious, don't you need a `change` event handlers that would be triggered by the dispatchEvent("change", ...)?

Comment: For example, as you can see here in this [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events)

Answer (score 0):

It's awful, and deprecated, but here's one way to do it:

```js
let selection = window.getSelection();
selection.removeAllRanges();
// remove any current selections
// and then select all children of the slate editor
for (let child of slateElement.children) {
    let range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNode(child);
    selection.addRange(range);
}
// finally use document.execCommand to put our desired replacement text in.
document.execCommand('insertText', false, 'Replacement Text');
```

(Note that if you're selecting a specific child that you want to change the text of, not the entire slate editor, you only need to select that one node)

As I mentioned, this is deprecated, it uses [`document.execCommand`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand), which for now works in all major browsers but there's no saying when it will stop.

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be writing the text directly to the internal `memoizedProps` property of the corresponding component. This is also how the BTTV browser plugin works for Twitch.

For an example on how the DOM from a Slate editor looks like you can check it out on their own [example page](https://www.slatejs.org/examples/richtext).

To get the editor node you can start with `document.querySelector('div[role="textbox"]');`.

Then you need to find the node which holds the proper data in `memoizedProps`. You can use the following helper functions from the [BTTV plugin](https://github.com/night/betterttv/blob/1723f4a8051a7e4ffda88e66cdde851ed53e5e2d/src/utils/twitch.js):

> ```
> function getChatInput(element = null) {
>     let chatInput;
>     try {
>         chatInput = searchReactParents(
>             getReactInstance(element),
>             (n) => n.memoizedProps
>                       && n.memoizedProps.componentType != null
>                       && n.memoizedProps.value != null
>         );
>     } catch (_) {}
>     return chatInput;
> }
>
> function getReactInstance(element) {
>     for (const key in element) {
>         if (key.startsWith('__reactInternalInstance$')) {
>             return element[key];
>         }
>     }
>     return null;
> }
>
> function searchReactParents(node, predicate, maxDepth = 15, depth = 0) {
>     try {
>         if (predicate(node)) {
>             return node;
>         }
>     } catch (_) {}
>     if (!node || depth > maxDepth) {
>         return null;
>     }
>     const {return: parent} = node;
>     if (parent) {
>         return searchReactParents(parent, predicate, maxDepth, depth + 1);
>     }
>     return null;
> }
> ```

When you found the correct node, then you can set the text like in the example below (it uses some lines from [another function from the BTTV plugin](https://github.com/night/betterttv/blob/1723f4a8051a7e4ffda88e66cdde851ed53e5e2d/src/utils/twitch.js#L582)):

```
var textbox = document.querySelector('div[role="textbox"]');
var textboxInput = getChatInput(textbox);
if (textboxInput == null) {
    return;
}
var text = 'example text set in slate editor';
textboxInput.memoizedProps.value = text;
textboxInput.memoizedProps.setInputValue(text);
textboxInput.memoizedProps.onValueUpdate(text);
```